# Is this kind of class hierarchy bad design?

Tags: java

The class hierarchy is like below:

A
|
B - List

Class B extends from A, and B contains a List of A

Comment: No. Check the composite pattern : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: It may or not, depending on your real use case. There is nothing really bad on a pattern point of view, but real use cases leading to that are uncommon. It is more common that A and B share a common ancestor. For example Point and Polygon could both share a common ancestor Position and Polygon contains a list of Points. You should share more of your actual context.